# Params in iron-router on the server

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a pretty simple route:

```
Router.route("/prospects/:_id", {
  name: "show.prospect",
  controller: "ProspectController"
});
```

That routes to the following route controller.

```
ProspectController = RouteController.extend({
  waitOn: function() {
    return [Meteor.subscribe("hits"), Meteor.subscribe("prospects")];
  },
  action: function() {
    return this.render('showProspect', {
      data: function() {
        var hits,
            prospect;
        // Without this line things blow up because this.params doesn't exist when executing this code on the server.
        if (Meteor.isServer)
          return;
        prospect = Prospects.findOne({ _id: this.params._id });
        hits = Hits.find({
          prospectId: prospect._id
        }, {
          sort: {
            createdAt: -1
          },
          limit: 6
        });
        return {
          prospect: prospect,
          hits: hits
        };
      }
    });
  }
});
```

If I attempt to execute the following line:

```
prospect = Prospects.findOne({ _id: this.params._id });
```

It doesn't find the prospect and I've learned this is because `this.params` is undefined when this code runs on the server.

Does anyone know why that is? I don't see a difference as to why it's available on the client and not the server. The controller is defined in the **both** folder so it's available to both client and server. Should I have defined it in the **client** folder?

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26343016/do-routecontrollers-need-to-be-defined-in-server-code-for-iron-router1-0-0-pre3) question, defining it in **both** is the correct approach.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to do 'server routing' which is a little different than what you are doing above, which affects the client. You might take a look at the 'Server Routing' section of the IR guide - https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using server-side routing elsewhere (a webhook). It's not what I need for this.

Comment: You'll probably need to do a Meteor.call to get the params on the server

Answer (score 0):

Lets with this.

```
ProspectController = RouteController.extend({
      waitOn: function() {
        return [Meteor.subscribe("hits"), Meteor.subscribe("prospects")];
      },
      action: function() {
        return this.render('showProspect', {
          data: function() {
            if(this.ready()){
            var hits,
                prospect;
            // Without this line things blow up because this.params doesn't exist when executing this code on the server.
            if (Meteor.isServer)
              return;
            prospect = Prospects.findOne({ _id: this.params._id });
            hits = Hits.find({
              prospectId: prospect._id
            }, {
              sort: {
                createdAt: -1
              },
              limit: 6
            });
            return {
              prospect: prospect,
              hits: hits
            };
          }
          }
        });
      }
    });
```

Here we added `if(this.ready()){}`, just to be sure we make the find when data is ready, seems like when you are using `waitOn and data` together, you should this.ready.

Take a look [here](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/1193)

Comment: I did not know this so thanks for that. However, the `data` option I'm specifying is as an option to the `render` function, not an option to the route controller. The issue you linked is for the route controller's `data` option.

Comment: what do you get console.log(this.params._id); undefined?

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to be exactly your problem, and the post is rather old, but I've ran into a very similar issue: `this.params` being not defined. My problem was that I had a custom constructor in my controller, and I forgot to call `RouteController`'s constructor. Therefore, most `RouteController`'s fields were not set. All I needed to fix was to call the `RouteController`'s  constructor from my controller's constructor. In Coffeescript, a single

```
super
```

statement was enough.